# Vite PWA service worker failing to register for react typescript

Tags: vite, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, react-typescript

I'm trying to register a custom service worker for my react typescript app. I really want to implement some custom functionality. I'm using `vite-pwa-plugin`, However it just keeps erroring in the browser:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at dev-sw.js?dev-sw:1:1)`

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8100/') with script ('http://localhost:8100/dev-sw.js?dev-sw'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed`

I have followed [this example](https://github.com/vite-pwa/vite-plugin-pwa/blob/main/examples/react-router/README.md) I found on the [vite-pwa-plugin guide](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/examples/react.html)

This is my `vite.config.ts`:

```
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import {VitePWA, VitePWAOptions} from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
const pwaOptions: Partial<VitePWAOptions> = {
  registerType: 'autoUpdate',
  strategies: 'injectManifest',
  srcDir: 'src',
  disable: false,
  filename: 'sw.ts',
  base: '/',
  includeAssets: ['favicon.svg'],
  devOptions: {
    enabled: true,
    type: 'module',
    navigateFallback: 'index.html',
  },
  
}
```

Here is my `sw.ts` file:

```
import { cleanupOutdatedCaches, createHandlerBoundToURL, precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching'
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core'
import { NavigationRoute, registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing'

declare let self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope

// self.__WB_MANIFEST is default injection point
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)

// clean old assets
cleanupOutdatedCaches()

let allowlist: undefined | RegExp[]
if (import.meta.env.DEV)
  allowlist = [/^\/$/]

// to allow work offline
registerRoute(new NavigationRoute(
  createHandlerBoundToURL('index.html'),
  { allowlist },
))

self.skipWaiting()
clientsClaim()
```

I already added the vite-pwa types to `vite-env.d.ts`